# Is it possible to release an app upgrade onto the Android Market at different times for different languages?

Tags: android, localization, google-play

I have an app upgrade ready for release, except for translations. It would be nice to give my English-speaking users their upgrade straight away, and make only the Germans wait until my (unpaid volunteer) translator is able to update the German text.

There's no obvious functionality on the Developer Console for this scenario. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible unless you separate each language to different APK and upload each. (Than restrict using location), and it doesn't seems like a good idea.
Most people just upload the new version with unfinished localization and upload a update after it's finished.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought, and it does seem like it would be a real headache.

Answer (score 1):

Martin, obviously from your question the German users have already gotten their hands on the app, so you may as well release one update now (for everyone) and then another more minor update once the unpaid volunteer has completed his grunt work.

Users hate to be left out. Especially the German users who already know enough English to use your application as it is. Trust me, almost everyone in Germany knows or speaks English, they just hate doing it :) (mind you, I can't say that about other countries)

Good luck, please  let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I don't really like the idea of half-translated releases very much, but I suppose it's better than no translation at all.